# Using foreach loop with methods in another class (Java)

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods, foreach

I have a program that creates a couple objects and adds each one to an ArrayList, then is supposed to loop over each object in the ArrayList and use a getter from another class within the project to display information on each object. I can't get the objects in my foreach loop to use any of the methods in my other class. Here is my main, including the trouble loop at the bottom:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ITECCourseManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList ITECCourse = new ArrayList();

        ITECCourse infotech = new ITECCourse("Info Tech Concepts", 1100, 5, "T3050");
        infotech.addStudent("Max");
        infotech.addStudent("Nancy");
        infotech.addStudent("Orson");
        ITECCourse.add(infotech);

        ITECCourse java = new ITECCourse("Java Programming", 2545, 3, "T3010");
        java.addStudent("Alyssa");
        java.addStudent("Hillary");
        ITECCourse.add(java);

        for (Object course : ITECCourse) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + course.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the other class in my project with the method I need to use:

```
public class ITECCourse {

    public String name;
    public int code;
    public ArrayList<String> students;
    public int maxStudents;
    public String room;

    ITECCourse(String courseName, int courseCode, int courseMaxStudents, String roomNum) {

        name = courseName;
        code = courseCode;
        maxStudents = courseMaxStudents;
        students = new ArrayList<String>();
        room = roomNum;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

If I replace course.getName() with java.getName(), the code works. I'm confused why I can't use a foreach loop across the ArrayList to use the getter for each object, when I am able to call the object and use the method directly from the same place in the code.

Edit: Thank you for the answers, simple mistake only had to make two/three changes: declare `ArrayList<ITECCourse>` at the beginning, change `Object` in `for` loop to `ITECCourse`, and of course change my arraylist from `ITECCourse` to `ITECCourseList` so there isn't confusion with my ITECCourse class.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: It's a very bad idea to name a variable identically to a class.

Comment: Think about it for one second. Does an `Object` have a method `getName()`?

Comment: Put another way, since Java is statically typed, you can only call a method on an object if that object is *declared* to have a type that has that method.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `course.getName()` doesn't work because you've defined `course` as an `Object` in your loop and `Object` doesn't have the method `getName()`.  If you add a type parameter to your `ArrayList` declaration such as `ArrayList<ITECCourse>`, then you can iterate over the list of `ITECCourse` instances rather than `Object`.

On a side note, naming your variable `ITECCourse` will just lead to confusion because it's the same as your class.  Might be better to name your variable something like `itecCourseList`.